# Questions regarding Kleros protocol — off-topic or not?

Tags: discussion, kleros

I want to create a public knowledge base about [Kleros protocol](https://kleros.io), the first decentralized dispute resolution system built on Ethereum and live since 2019. So initially, mostly I will be asking and answering myself, and hopefully other users will take off from there.

I wonder if Q&A regarding Kleros would be off or on-topic in this forum. I believe it's on-topic since it's something built on top of Ethereum, but I wanted to ask in Meta just in case.

Comment: Upvoted your question. I don't know. If not much comments/answers, it seems you can give it a shot.

Comment: >  I believe it's on-topic since it's something built on top of Ethereum

I agree with this. While questions about Kleros arent really about Ethereum in itself, there are lots of questions about other protocols built on top of Ethereum like Uniswap and such. I see no reason why a question about Kleros would be considered off topic.